# Integrate chatbot to sharepoint

Tags: python, sharepoint, chatbot, streamlit

I would like to know what technology is best to use to integrate chat-bot to share-point, idea is to have that fancy chat-bubble at the corner of the screen.

I have bot running on server using streamlit as front-end and python as back-end.